# Squid is not caching artifacts from sotatype nexus maven repository

Tags: nexus, squid

I'm trying to set up Squid to cache all the requests for corporate maver repository. Initially I've succeeded doing this with Ivy, but now Squid should cache data from Sonatype Nexus respository, referenced by Maven.

My problem is that Squid is not actually caching Maven artifacts. We are using lots of snapshot dependencies, so I'm Ok with refreshing artifacts metadata on each build, but I do not understand, why aftifacts are not refreshed themselves.

In Squid log, I have the following

```
1438258641.794   7852 127.0.0.1 TCP_CLIENT_REFRESH_MISS/200 8872504 GET http://build.mycompany.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/com/mycompany/com.mycompany.platform/5.4-SNAPSHOT/com.mycompany.platform-5.4-20150730.074224-34.jar - HIER_DIRECT/10.10.150.213 application/java-archive
```

After this I go and remove the whole artifact's directory from ~/.m2/repository, I see TCP_CLIENT_REFRESH_MISS once more for the same artifact during the next build:

```
1438259631.440   7398 127.0.0.1 TCP_CLIENT_REFRESH_MISS/200 8872504 GET http://build.mycompany.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/com/mycompany/com.mycompany.platform/5.4-SNAPSHOT/com.mycompany.platform-5.4-20150730.074224-34.jar - HIER_DIRECT/10.10.150.213 application/java-archive
```

According to description of TCP_CLIENT_REFRESH_MISS (and observed artifact download time), artifact is reloaded from server, instead of caching.

Answer (score 1):

"This seems to be the documented behavior. The default Maven wagon for HTTP (i.e., the "lightweight" client) does not seem to allow disabling these headers.
Actually, you can configure the Lightweight HTTP Wagon client using the available setters, for example (Maven 2.0+):"

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>central</id>
    <configuration>
      <useCache>true</useCache>
    </configuration>
  </server>
</servers>
```

Or even override or provide additional HTTP headers (Maven 2.1+):

```
<server>
  <id>central</id>
  <configuration>
    <httpHeaders>
      <property>
        <name>User-Agent</name>
        <value>Internal-Build-System/1.0</value>
      </property>
    </httpHeaders>
  </configuration>
</server>
```

Source: [Why does Maven disable caching for HTTP requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054884/why-does-maven-disable-caching-for-http-requests)